# Did any country lambast or criticize South Africa's ICJ application against Israel except the U.S. and Israel?

Tags: united-states, israel, western-world, international-court-of-justice, south-africa

> The Biden regime rose to defend its staunch ally Israel. U.S. National
> Security Council spokesman John Kirby lambasted South Africa’s ICJ
> application as “meritless, counterproductive and completely without
> any basis in fact whatsoever.” Kirby claimed, “Israel is not trying to
> wipe the Palestinian people off the map. Israel is not trying to wipe
> Gaza off the map. Israel is trying to defend itself against a
> genocidal terrorist threat,” echoing Israel’s preposterous assertion.

https://truthout.org/articles/israel-is-terrified-the-world-court-will-decide-its-committing-genocide/

Did any country lambast or criticize South Africa's ICJ application against Israel aside the U.S. and Israel? I am curious, because many Western countries have a significant Muslim population, so I am wondering if there are countries, especially Western countries that decided to voice a negative opinion on South Africa ICJ application.

Comment: Ambassador NDeRiviere says that France, as a strong supporter of the ICJ, will support its decision [clip link](https://twitter.com/Deeyah_Khan/status/1742665643122454811)

Comment: Please define ICJ for future readers.

Comment: Your question isn't clear - do you want to know if *any* country criticised SA's ICJ petition or do you want to know if any western nation, with muslim minority population, criticised SA's ICJ petition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Germany to request join as third party in Hague case: 'Israel is not committing genocide'](https://www.ynetnews.com/article/byhdml1tp):

> The German government strongly rejected Friday the accusations made at the UN's top court that Israel is committing "genocide" in Gaza and cautions against the "political instrumentalization" of such charges.
>
> [...]
>
> Government spokesperson Hebestreit acknowledges differing perspectives globally regarding Israel's ground offensive operation against Hamas in Gaza. However, he emphatically states, **"The German government firmly and explicitly rejects the accusation of genocide leveled against Israel before the International Court of Justice. The allegation lacks factual basis."**

This information is confirmed by [Deutsche Welle](https://p.dw.com/p/4bBee):
[image]

*Position of EU states*
[Euronews reports that EU as a whole adopted a neutral position](https://www.euronews.com/my-europe/2024/01/12/where-do-eu-countries-stand-on-south-africas-genocide-case-against-israel), with  Germany, Austria, and Czech republic expressing skepticism about the case:

> Germany, Austria and the Czech Republic - all considered staunch allies of Israel - have voiced scepticism about the case.
>
> Speaking from Israel on Thursday as the hearing took place in the Hague, Germany's Vice Chancellor Robert Habeck said: **"You can criticise the Israeli army for acting too harshly in the Gaza strip, but that is not genocide."**
>
> "Those who would commit or want to commit genocide, if they could, are Hamas," Habeck added. "Their agenda is to wipe out the State of Israel."
>
> In a joint statement issued Thursday, the Austrian Chancellor and Czech Prime Minister expressed similar doubts.
>
> "We oppose any attempts to politicize the ICJ," the leaders said in a joint statement.

Hungary openly condemned South Africa:

> Hungary is the only country that has explicitly condemned South Africa's ICJ case, with foreign minister Péter Szijjártó denouncing the "legal attack launched against Israel" on social media platform Facebook.
>
> "To accuse a country that has suffered a terrorist attack of genocide is obviously nonsense," Szijjártó said. "We believe that it is in the interest of the whole world that the current anti-terrorist operations are successfully completed in order to prevent such a brutal terrorist attack from happening anywhere in the world ever again."

The countries most supportive of Gaza and the immediate ceasefire, such as Belgium, Ireland, and Spain either expressed skepticism about the case or avoided commenting altogether:

> Irish Taoiseach Leo Varadkar, whose government has been hailed as one of the most supportive of Palestinian statehood across Europe, has ruled out any possibility Ireland would join the case, despite pressure from Irish lawmakers.
>
> "I really think this is an area where we need to be very careful," > Varadkar told RTÉ Radio over the weekend.
>
> **"Hamas went into Israel (on October 7), killed 1,400 people (...) essentially because they were Israelis, because they were Jews, because they lived in Israel. Was that not also genocide?"** Varadkar questioned.

*Beyond the EU*
According to [another Euronews piece](https://www.euronews.com/2024/01/14/genocide-case-against-israel-where-does-the-rest-of-the-world-stand-on-allegations):

> The majority of countries backing South Africa's case are from the Arab world and Africa.
>
> In Europe, only the Muslim nation of **Turkey has publicly stated its support**.
>
> No Western country has declared support for South Africa's allegations against Israel. The US, a close Israel ally, has rejected them as unfounded, the UK has called them unjustified, and Germany said it "explicitly rejects" them.
>
> **China and Russia have said little** about one of the most significant cases to come before an international court in recent history - and the European Union also hasn't commented.

Comment: The German position was emphatically refuted by the [President of Namibia](https://twitter.com/NamPresidency/status/1746259880871149956)

Comment: @ccprog Namibia doesn't make decisions for Germans. Neither do the past German crimes make Israel any more or less guilty.